# Find the acute angle that has the same sin, cos, and tan values as...

Tags: trigonometry

$5\pi$ radians, $-450$ degrees, $\frac{11}{2}\pi$

$5\pi$ radians is exactly the same as $\pi$ radians, but $\pi$ is not an acute angle.  How should I answer this question?  Also, $-450$ degrees is the same as $90$ degrees.  Again, this is not acute. How do I answer this?

Also, $\frac{11}{2}\pi$ is the same as $\frac{3}{2}\pi$.  Again, not acute.

Comment: This is a peculiar question. If two angles have the same sine and cosine, then they will always have the same tangent (since the last is just the ratio of the first two). Furthermore, it is not always possible to find an acute angle with a given sine and cosine, since every angle in $[0,2\pi)$ has a distinct (ordered) pair of sine and cosine values. Are you sure you really meant what you asked?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact question. I copy pasted it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :-
find refrence angle , then consider its sighn to get same sin/cos/tan

Comment: Yes, I did that.  But none of those angles are acute angles.

Comment: ok for 5 /pi , i thought of zero :o , but  cos 5pi is negative :-\